# How to pass jquery selections into a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I tried searching, but couldn't quite find what I was looking for. Hopefully this is super simple for someone.

This is the code i'm starting with that i'd like to turn into a function. Obviously there is a way to do this so I don't have to repeat.

```
var fullWidth = $('.full-img').width();
var paddBottom = fullWidth * .75;
$('.full-img').css('padding-bottom', paddBottom);

var thumbWidth = $('.img-box').width();
var thumbBottom = thumbWidth * .75;
$('.img-box').css('padding-bottom', thumbBottom);
```

Here's what I tried

```
function aspectRatioFix(main, thumb) {
    var fullWidth = main.width();
    var paddBottom = fullWidth * .75;
    main.css('padding-bottom', paddBottom);

    var thumbWidth = thumb.width();
    var thumbBottom = thumbWidth * .75;
    thumb.css('padding-bottom', thumbBottom);
}

    aspectRatioFix('.full-img', '.img-box');
```

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: main.width is not a function"

Is there a way to maybe loop through my function to take care of both parts of my script instead of just duplicating what I have?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to reselect or can you store it in memory? Or said otherwise, are your images dynamically added to the page? In any case, there's a selector object on every jQuery object, pass it in directly, or refetch every function call.

Comment: They will be dynamically added to the page on load before i run this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `aspectRatioFix` is expecting jQuery objects so you'll have to pass in jQuery objects instead of selectors (strings) like this:

```
aspectRatioFix($('.full-img'), $('.img-box'));
```

If you have many images and their thumbs and you want to apply the code for all of them then use `.each` like this:

```
var $mains = $('.full-img'),
    $thumbs = $('.img-box');

$mains.each(function(index) {
    // this:  is the main image
    // index: is its index so we can access the according thumb from $thumbs

    aspectRatioFix($(this), $($thumbs[index])); // apply the aspectRatioFix on this main image, and on it's thumb from the $thumbs object (both this and $thumbs[index] are node elements so we have to wrap them in a jQuery object using $())
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I don't have many images and their thumbs, just by using the classes it takes care of them all.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending plain strings and not selectors to your function, you would have to do it like this:

```
function aspectRatioFix(main, thumb) {
    var fullWidth = main.width();
    var paddBottom = fullWidth * .75;
    main.css('padding-bottom', paddBottom);

    var thumbWidth = thumb.width();
    var thumbBottom = thumbWidth * .75;
    thumb.css('padding-bottom', thumbBottom);
}

aspectRatioFix($('.full-img'), $('.img-box'));
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest is simply caching your jQuery objects.
A simple [DOM ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event inside an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) which can be copy/pasted into a separate js file:

```
// IIFE
(function(scope, $){
    // this configuration
    var cfg = {
        cache: {
            fullImg: '.full-img',
            imgBox: '.img-box'
        },
        options: {
            modifier: 0.75,
            css: 'padding-bottom'
        }
    };

    // function declaration
    function aspectRatioFix(elements, options){
        $.each(elements, function(){
           var el = $(this),
               paddBottom = el.width() * options.modifier;
           el.css(options.css, paddBottom);
        });
    }

    // DOM ready to execute
    $(function(){
        var fullImg = $(cfg.cache.fullImg);
        //var imgBox = $(cfg.cache.imgBox);

        aspectRatioFix(fullImg, cfg.options);
        aspectRatioFix($(cfg.cache.imgBox), cfg.options);
    });
}(window, window.jQuery));
```

The way I refactor things into functional (in this case) and modular approaches is to move every string in the code to `cfg` object literal. The code becomes more clear to separate.

And to add real quickly: `aspectRatioFix($('.a-new-selector'), cfg.options);` 
In case of the accepted answer you'll have to edit the function again while you should avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

```
function aspectRatioFix(main, thumb) { 
    var fullWidth = main.width(); 
    var paddBottom = fullWidth * .75; 
    main.css('padding-bottom', paddBottom); 
    var thumbWidth = thumb.width(); 
    var thumbBottom = thumbWidth * .75;
    thumb.css('padding-bottom', thumbBottom);
 } 
 aspectRatioFix($('.full-img'), $('.img-box'));
```

Comment: Please use proper code styling when posting answers.